# Two Kafka consumer with same groupid, four topics with 0 partition

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

two instances are running to my same Kafka consumer with using same groupid, I have 4 topics with 0 partition. below is my YAML configuration:

```
consumer:
  bootstrap-servers:  ${KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS}
  group-id: group-id
  key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
  value-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
  enable-auto-commit: false
  auto-offset-reset: earliest
  max-poll-records: 10
  max-poll-interval-ms: 660000
  properties:
    max:
      poll:
        interval:
          ms: 300000
  session:
    timeout:
      ms: 300000
    heartbeat:
      interval:
        ms: 25000
listener:
  ack-mode: MANUAL_IMMEDIATE
```

I am observing my both instances log, when one instance is working properly then other is throwing error : org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing the session timeout or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.

then second one works fine and first one throwing error. and while processing the records bellow message is continuously coming:

2020-05-05 15:57:52.874  INFO 23804 --- [onnectorservice] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=group-id] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing

but message got processed successfully. and after all this my all messages got successfully processed. 
what exactly i need to change to avoid these errors.

this is happening when one consumer goes down and restart again: after that only error are in logs comes.

Comment: If you want to increase parallelism, increase number of partitions not number of consumers. In Kafka Rule of thumb is to keep Consumer to partition ratio 1:1, this applies to same_consumer_grp. You have consumer group idea to make other set of consumers consume same data as the first consumer grp. Or have partitions divided into consumer grp.

Comment: if you have 4 partitions then you can have 4 consumers in the same_group/ 2 consumer in first grp, 2 more consumers in teh second grp.. If you have 1 partition then in the same_group, you should have only one consumer. Else other consumer which consumed the same message cant commit. It fails, however its consumed and committed by another consumer.

Comment: Is there a way if i polled 10 messages and during processing of the records i encounter "can not commit " exception and when i catch this exception, can i remove in-memory message through code whatever left?

Comment: If you poll (poll is just a mechanism for number of msgs at once) & read already, it gets committed automatically as you process that msg (log this msg with kafka-offset-id). set auto-commit = true. why doing it manually? if process fails and have exception, then that msg wont be committed automatically again. what do you mean by in-memory msg to be removed within code? if the exception happened, its not committed, but in the next poll it will be read again. why bother to remove within code, just log its not processed with msg offset-id and check the log did that get processed successfully?